# How do i get textDetection and LabelDetection with NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

```
const results = await visionClient.labelDetection(imageUri).safeSearchDetection(imageUri);
```

i am trying to get an image response with cloud vision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it this way for version 0.21.0

```
import * as vision from '@google-cloud/vision';
const visionClient = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const request = {
                "image": {
                    "source": {
                        "imageUri": imageUri
                    }
                },
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "FACE_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "LABEL_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "WEB_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "CROP_HINTS"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "IMAGE_PROPERTIES"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "LOGO_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "LANDMARK_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TYPE_UNSPECIFIED"
                    },
                    // Other detection types here...
                ]
        };

        return await visionClient.annotateImage(request).then((res) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of code for an HTTPS Cloud Function that will do the OCR (i.e. text detection) of an image stored in Firebase Storage. You would, for example, call it from your app after you have uploaded an image to Firebase Storage (in the `gs://myproject.com/imgtoocr/` bucket), by passing the image name in the body of the HTTP Request.

```
....
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();


exports.imageOCR = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const imageFilename = req.body.imageFilename;

    let result;

    return client
      .documentTextDetection(
        'gs://myproject.com/imgtoocr/' + imageFilename
      )
      .then(results => {
        const blocks = results[0].fullTextAnnotation.pages[0].blocks;

        blocks.forEach(blockDetail => {
          blockDetail.paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
            //Here you build the result you want to send back
          });
        });

        return {
          result: result
        };
      })
      .then(ocrResult => {
        return res.status(200).json(ocrResult);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
        res.status(400).send(err);
      });
  });
});
```

You will find more info and examples (in particular for Label Detection) in the following documentation for node.js:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr-tutorial

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.19.x/

Comment: now how do i get the ocrDetection and labelDetection in one request i wonder?

Comment: Just call `client.labelDetection(imageFilename).then(results => {})
  .catch(err => {});` in parallel of calling `client.documentTextDetection()`

Comment: @yushin Hi, did you have time to give a try?